# Digital height of an option

Tags: options, trading

Could someone please help me explain the concept of Digital Height clearly in the options world? Thank you

Comment: Hello @OptionsTradingFinancier: if you like my answer, could you pls click on the tick mark to accept it and then your question will be marked as "answered"? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digital option pays the amount $\delta$ if it ends up in the money otherwise it pays zero. Therefore, the pay-off diagram (pay-off on the y-axis, underlying price on the x-axis) looks like a straight line that starts at $S_T = K$ and the y-axis value of this straight line is equal to $y=\delta$. In other words, the "height" of the pay-off is equal to the digital option pay-off.

In the diagram below, $\delta = C$ and therefore the "height" of the digital option pay-off is $C$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for a really good explanation. So the digital height for any type of option is the the difference between the value of the option being ITM or expires worthless?